# put background color transition before video start

Tags: html, css, video

i have a doubt that i don't seem to figure out how to solve, basicly i have a video that is a video apresentation of my website, what i want is, to show a image before the video starts playing, so i can prevent the user to see that loop before starting the video, and if there is a connection problem, the image is showing always.

At the moment i have this:

```
     <section class="tp-banner-container content_section">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe id="video" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kn-1D5z3-Cs?autoplay=1&showinfo=0
&start=10&controls=0&modestbranding=1" volume="0">
             </iframe>
            </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: because you are using a youtube hosted video in an iframe you won't be able to use HTML Video events to see when it has loaded/canplay etc, so you'll need to explore the youTube API to see if it has callbacks that will let you know when to hide the color overlay (or host the video yourself and use the HTML5 events to trigger actions)

Answer (score 0):

> you need samply using attr poster and give some height and width.

```
 <video width="470" height="255" poster="placeholder.png" controls>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <object data="video.mp4" width="470" height="255">
        <embed src="video.swf" width="470" height="255">
        </object>
    </video>
```

Comment: well sorry, i don't want a image, i want a background color :/

Comment: @FilipeCosta the poster can be a solid color?

Comment: hmmm, isn't there a problem that my video is from youtube, sorry but yesterday i was searching a lot and seems like i must use iframe can you help me with that?